# When i try to create react project i get error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying create a react app but when i execute this command (My IDE's default command)

> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js" --ignore-existing
> create-react-app .

I get this error

```
npx: installed 91 in 20.183s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\GreXLin85\WebstormProjects\blogandportfolio.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error postcss@8.1.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^10 || ^12 || >=14". Got "13.12.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd C:\Users\GreXLin85\WebstormProjects\blogandportfolio has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

> I tried update "node" and "npm" but not worked
> My node and npm versions

```
C:\Users\GreXLin85\WebstormProjects\blogandportfolio>node -v
v13.12.0

C:\Users\GreXLin85\WebstormProjects\blogandportfolio>npm -v
6.14.8
```

Comment: looks like the error is because node is still 13.12.0. You can go to the [node download page](https://nodejs.org/en/) and get the latest. The command 'node -v' should give you 14.xx.xx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is the node error use this link to update node to latest ref: https://medium.com/stackfame/how-to-update-node-js-to-latest-version-linux-ubuntu-osx-windows-others-105749e90040